# Writing template functions accepting inputs of type cv::Mat or cv::UMat

Tags: c++, opencv, templates, mat

What is the simplest and cleanest way to write a function accepting input arguments of type Mat or UMat?

Should I use InputArray, use templates or is there a better alternative? I am currenlty having functions with identical implementation written for both Mat and UMat.

The function should take full advantage of the UMat abstraction over OpenCL, and running roughly as fast as if it was written just for UMats, and without the overhead of having to copy UMats to Mats.

An example of function which I could want to define for both Mat and UMat is the following (please do not propose refactoring to remove local Mat/UMat variables, this is just an example)

```
using namespace cv;    

void foo(const Mat & in1, const Mat & in2, Mat & out)
{
    Mat aux1;
    Mat aux2;
    exp(in1, aux1);
    exp(in2, aux2);
    add(aux1, aux2, out);
    return;
}

void foo(const UMat & in1, const UMat & in2, UMat & out)
{
    UMat aux1;
    UMat aux2;
    exp(in1, aux1);
    exp(in2, aux2);
    add(aux1, aux2, out);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can use [InputArray](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html), like all OpenCV functions

Comment: Is this the most convenient option? from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details I read "The class is designed solely for passing parameters. That is, normally you should not declare class members, local and global variables of this type.". My functions do declare/use local Mats/UMats depending on the input type

Comment: Please provide some code examples. "Most convenient" isn't really well defined

Comment: Looks like a classical template thing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a template:

```cpp
using namespace cv;    

// MatType is either cv::Mat or cv::UMat.
template<typename MatType>
void foo(const MatType& in1, const MatType& in2, MatType& out)
{
    MatType aux1;
    MatType aux2;
    exp(in1, aux1);
    exp(in2, aux2);
    add(aux1, aux2, out);
    return;
}
```

Advantages:

- It is easy to declare local `Mat`s or `UMat`s depending on the input type.
- No `Mat` ⟷ `UMat` conversion.

Disadvantage:

- All matrix arguments must be of the same type, it is not possible to mix `Mat`s and `UMat`s.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested by @Miki and @Gianni, we can choose [`InpputArray` and `OutputArray`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details) for the general template types of  `Mat, Mat_<T>, Matx<T, m, n>, std::vector<T>, std::vector<std::vector<T> >, std::vector<Mat>, std::vector<Mat_<T> >, UMat, std::vector<UMat> or double.`

```
void func(InputArray _src1, InputArray _src2, OutputArray _dst)
{
    Mat src1 = _src1.getMat(), src2 = _src2.getMat();
    CV_Assert( src1.type() == src2.type() && src1.size() == src2.size());
    Mat aux1 = Mat(src1.size(), src1.type());
    Mat aux2 = Mat(src1.size(), src1.type());
    cv::exp(src1, aux1);
    cv::exp(src2, aux2);

    _dst.create(src1.size(), src1.type());
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();
    cv::add(aux1, aux2, dst);
}
```

Now you can test it with `Mat` or `UMat` or even `std::vector`

```
int test(){
    std::vector<float> vec1 = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<float> vec2 = {3,2,1};
    std::vector<float> dst;

    func(vec1, vec2, dst);
    // now dst is [22.8038, 14.7781, 22.8038]

}
```

Comment: I suddenly realize that maybe it is not right for `GpuMat`. But I haven't test.

Comment: +1 because it is actually effective. But I would like to take advantage of the  UMat abstraction: here my UMats will be converted to Mats and my exp() and add() calls will run in CPU. I also would not like to have to move memory form device to host with a .getMat() call as this could mean significant additional processing overhead. I will edit my question as it probably was not clear